# How to fix size exceeds expected in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to loop over Excel files with python `pandas`. First I'm saving them to csv and then I open them again, slice and then saving them again. But I get an error:

```
"Workbook: size exceeds expected 10752 bytes; corrupt?"
```

I am relatively new to python.

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: How many rows and how many columns?

Comment: it seems that pandas uses `xlrd` to read excel files and `xlrd` raises an [error](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/bbccdcb96e40b590d71ed14682237bea1e8f1dc5/xlrd/compdoc.py#L435) if it feels something is wrong about reading the file... which is what happened to you.

Answer (score 4):

I could fix this exact error **by just opening the problematic Excel file in Excel and simply saving it**.

After that I could import the file in Pandas without the error.

In my case I suspect that this error results from a platform inconsistancy in Excel between Windows (where my source files were generated) and Mac OS (where I import the files).

Comment: I am facing the same issue with files generated on Windows and processed on Mac OS. Did you find any solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a cell that has more than 255 characters in it.

See this article about data and file size limitations: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/jet-data-file-size-limitations

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to open your Excel files instead.

It seems that pandas uses [`xlrd`](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to read excel files and `xlrd` raises an [error](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/bbccdcb96e40b590d71ed14682237bea1e8f1dc5/xlrd/compdoc.py#L435) if it feels something is wrong about reading the file... which is what happened to you.

`xlrd` is no longer maintained as of Jan 2020.