# How to re-save excel files within a directory using Python?

Tags: python, excel

I have a bunch of Excel files (.xls) in a given directory (C:\ucustom\myfiles).  I want to programmatically use Python v3.6 to re-save each of these files in the same directory.  How do I do that? (no need to open each file, just need to save each .xls file again in place).  Thanks!

Comment: What is the aim of this exercise?

Comment: What does it even mean to save a closed file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congratulations on your first question! Please consider rewriting your question so it follows [the best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This way you get closer to a relevant answer, sooner. Start by explaining the purpose of what you pursue so you could find more efficient ways of doing it, or share the steps you already did or what you have already tried and researched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix size exceeds expected in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512813/how-to-fix-size-exceeds-expected-in-python-3)

Comment: As it turns out, you really *do* have to open the files to fix them. And you specifically have to open them in Excel, because how they are getting fixed is that Excel is kind of tolerant of certain errors upon loading, but then is rewriting them properly, with all the i's dotted and the t's crossed. As someone commented, you can automate that process using things like PyAutoGUI. There are other Python choices like xlwings. Or you could use VBScript or AutoHotkey. In all cases, you have to have Excel for it to work.

Comment: @John Y Thanks for your inputs!  Can you please share some code which uses PyAutoGui to open and save Excel files automatically? Or perhaps code using xlwings to do this taksk?  Anything would help me at this point. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The following code will resave all `xls` files in the directory (for example, `1.xls` will be saved as `COPY OF 1.xls`).

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile

directory = "C:\\ucustom\\myfiles"

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".xls"):
        copyfile(os.path.join(directory, filename),
            os.path.join(directory, "COPY OF " + filename))
```

Comment: But this doesn't resave the files in place, without opening them. OP seems to want to modify the metadata of existing files, so that their time of last access is modified.

Comment: @JohnColeman If that's what is needed, won't it suffice to run `touch` for each file through `os.system()`?

Comment: @AnoopRDesai That might be OP is trying to do. I was just guessing as to their intent. `touch` itself seems to be a Linux utility, but the functionality is given more directly in the `pathlib` module in the `Path.touch()` method.

Comment: Ah right, I forgot to mention my assumption of it being on Linux. I wasn't aware of the `pathlib` module. Thanks for that!

Comment: @AnoopRDesai The reason I need to do this is to avoid a Python error which comes up everytime I try to open up any of these .xls files using my Editor.  "CompDocError: Workbook: size exceeds expected 4608 bytes; corrupt?" when I tried to read in a given file's content by using (pandas) pd.read_excel("file_name.xls"). To avoid this error, I found that I would have to open the file and re-save it manually.  After a file has been re-saved, the error no longer occurs.  I have hundreds of these files in my directory, so need to resave these programmatically to avoid the error mentioned.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess you'll have to look into something like `pyautogui`, if opening the files and resaving them is the only way to fix them.

Comment: @student2019 I see a similar question - [How to fix size exceeds expected in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512813/how-to-fix-size-exceeds-expected-in-python-3) but with no accepted answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman - Unix's `touch` (quite accurately replicated by Python 3's `Path.touch`) is both a file creator and a timestamp updater. A more "pure" way to update timestamps is with `os.utime` (present since the very early days of Python).

Comment: @AnoopRDesai - Knowing what we now know (given OP's comment), I'd go so far as to say this is a duplicate question.